# C++ cin.getline appears to be skipped

Tags: c++

I can't quite figure out why my program below is skipping over "cin.getline(staffMember, 100);". If I add a delimiter like 'q' for instance, it works as expected. I'm not sure why it's acting as if a new line is being entered automatically. Could somebody please explain to me why this is happening?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> // Allow use of the ifstream and ofstream statements
#include <cstdlib> // Allow use of the exit statement

using namespace std;

ifstream inStream;
ofstream outStream;

void showMenu();
void addStaffMember();

void showMenu()
{
    int choice;

    do
    {
        cout 
            << endl
            << "Press 1 to Add a New Staff Member.\n"
            << "Press 2 to Display a Staff Member.\n"
            << "Press 3 to Delete a Staff Member.\n"
            << "Press 4 to Display a Report of All Staff Members.\n"
            << "Press 5 to Exit.\n"
            << endl
            << "Please select an option between 1 and 5: ";

        cin >> choice;

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                addStaffMember();

                break;
            case 2:
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            case 5:
                break;
            default:
                cout << "You did not select an option between 1 and 5. Please try again.\n";
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
}

void addStaffMember()
{
    char staffMember[100];

    cout << "Full Name: ";

    cin.getline(staffMember, 100);

    outStream.open("staffMembers.txt", ios::app);
    if (outStream.fail())
    {
        cout << "Unable to open staffMembers.txt.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    outStream << endl << staffMember;

    outStream.close();
}

int main()
{
    showMenu();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user enters a choice, they type a number and then press enter. This puts that input including a `\n` character into the input stream. When you do `cin >> choice`, characters will be extracted until the `\n` is found and then those characters will be interpreted as an `int`. However, the `\n` is still in the stream.

Later, when you do `cin.getline(staffMember, 100)`, it reads up to the `\n` and appears as though you entered a new line without actually typing anything.

To get around this, extract up to the next new line by using `ignore`:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

This will extract everything up until and including the next `\n` character and discard it. So in fact, this will even handle when the user inputs something like `1banana`. The `1` will be extracted by `cin >> choice` and then the rest of the line will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

When doing `cin >> choice;` the newline is left by `cin`. So when you do `getline` next, it reads up to this newline and returns empty (or whitespace) string.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
scanf("%d\n", &choice);
```

OR you can use a dummy getchar() after cin>>choice;

Right now, the `\n` is skipped, as explained in few answers.

Answer (score 0):

`cin` is mixed with `getline()` - try not to mix both in the same code.

Try using this instead?

```
char aa[100];
// After using cin 
std::cin.ignore(1);
cin.getline(aa, 100);
//....
```